# Spring Boot Application - How can I pass data (list in list) from controller to Thymeleaf based on current object?

Tags: html, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working on a Thymeleaf template in a Spring Boot application. I am getting the data correctly in my controller but I am not sure how to proceed in my template. I have a summary table that is related to a user, a user can have many summaries.Each summary item can have a note. And there can be many notes per summary.

Would it be better practice to include a note id on the summary table(some summary items might not contain a note) or since I am getting the data correctly in the controller the logic for my template is off?

This is how I am getting data in my controller:

```
modelAtt.addObject("sumList", summaryService.getList(currentUser));

List<Notes> note = notService.getList(summary.getId());
modelAtt.addObject("noteList", note);
```

This is how I am trying to loop through in my template(instead of showing a note per summary I am showing the current notes but under every summary item the user has instead of under the summary the note belongs to):

```
<div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(sumList)}">
  <div th:each="sum : ${sumList}">
    <tr>
      <th>Summary</th>
    </tr>
    <td th:text="${sum.description}"></td>
    <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(noteList)}">
      <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
      <tr th:each="note : ${noteList}">
        <td th:text="${note.description}"></td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Edits**

`Service` class:

```
public List<Summary> getList(User user) {
    return summaryRepository.summaryByUser(user);
}

public List<Note> getList(int id) {
    Summary summary = summaryService.findOne(caseId);
    return noteRepository.noteBySum(summary);
}
```

`Repo` class:

```
@Query("select a from summary a where a.user = ?1")
List<Summary> summaryByUser(User user);

@Query("select a from note a where a.summary = ?1")
List<Note> noteBySum(Summary summary);
```

Comment: It is still confusing.  Add more details about the data structure

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb apologies for the confusion. I am getting the data correctly in my controller but Im having trouble representing the data in my template. The Summary table has user id on it and Notes table has a summary id on it. So I created a list of summary by getting all the summary items related to the current user and for notes I do the same except Im getting the list based off the current summary id. Does that make sense?

Comment: If using JPA, you should just get the summary and select the fetch type.  This will bring everything automatically.  Check http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading .Also, show the objects and how they are linked.  I suggest using JPA with hibernate for better ORM and data structures

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how this would help? I am able to get the data (all summary items on user and all notes on summary) but I do not think I am passing it to the template correctly. (the template shows all notes under all summary items). So it looks like Summary 1: note 1, note 2 Summary 2: note 1, note 2. When it should be summary 1: note 1 summary 2: note 2.

Comment: If you only want to fix this part, show your service code.  JPA would help in that you would only get the all summaries for a user only.  Then, JPA-hibernate will link all related objects (notes) and bring them as well

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb ok, thanks...see edits above

Comment: The issue with your approach is that you are getting all summaries in the summary list (`sumList`), but only putting notes for `summary.getId()`.  What you want is to access the notes directly from Summary.  Loop all summaries then for each summary loop on `summary.notes` directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I think I got the question wrong the first time after checking your edits. So you have a list of notes for every Summary? You need to associate each Summary with List of Notes when passing the data to your Thymeleaf template. You could do it by using JPA associations (@OneToMany) or change your controller code somewhat like below to return a map instead of a list.

```
List<Summary> summaryList = summaryService.getList(currentUser));
Map<Integer,List<Note>> noteListMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Summary summary : summaryList) {
    noteListMap.put(summary.getId(),noteService.getList(summary.getId()))
}
modelAtt.addObject("sumList", summaryList);
modelAtt.addObject("noteListMap", noteListMap);
```

Then your template could be

```
<div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(sumList)}">
<div th:each="sum : ${sumList}">
    <tr>
        <th>Summary</th>
    </tr>
    <td th:text="${sum.description}"></td>
    <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(noteListMap[__${sum.id}__])}">
          <tr>
             <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
        <tr th:each="note : ${noteListMap[__${sum.id}__])}">
            <td th:text="${note.description}"></td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, this is what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you!